# Drag and drop image not working in tinymce text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using http://www.tinymce.com plugin in ASP.NET C# Project.
I have added the following code in aspx page

```
 <script src="../Scripts/TinyEditor/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar1: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Now, whenever we drag image and then drop it in the text area, it doesn't get inserted in the textarea... Please help me!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to enable the image drag & drop feature you have to do it explicitly with the code below.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    paste_data_images: true
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. images just redirect the browser to the path of the dragged image.